# Ordinary kriging questions

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, kriging

really newbie here. I would like to do an ordinary kriging on missing rainfall value.Here is my code.

```
 from pykrige.ok import OrdinaryKriging
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd

 fname = "C:/Users/Tan/Desktop/sample1.csv"
 df = pd.read_csv(fname)
 fname1 = "C:/Users/Tan/Desktop/sample2.csv"
 df1 = pd.read_csv(fname1)
 z = []
 ss = []

for column in df1:

data = df1[column]
complete = []
lon1 = []
lat1 = []
lon2 = []
lat2 = []

for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if data[i] != "" :
        complete.append(data[i])
        lon1.append(df['longitude'][i])
        lat1.append(df['latitude'][i])

    else:
        lon2.append(df['longitude'][i])
        lat2.append(df['latitude'][i])


OK = OrdinaryKriging(lon1, lat1, complete, variogram_model='linear', verbose=False,
                     enable_plotting=False, coordinates_type='geographic')
z, ss= OK.execute('grid', lon2, lat2)

z.append(z)
```

But I keep received **[ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity]**
Please advise if there is another better way to solve this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Null` values from your data and then try again. I hope this will work for you. Thanks!